# How to escape back-references in gsub replacement strings

Tags: ruby

There is some alternative to gsub that justs replaces one string occurrence with another?

Acording to docs "If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form \d, where d is a group number, or \k, where n is a group name."

I don't want this functionality..

simplified example:

```
"abc".gsub("b", "\\7") -> "ac"
```

and I want `"a\7c"`..

**The problem is that the replacement string is asked from the user** (actually it's a path that containts `"xxx\7.0\yyy"`), if it's simple a fixed string I could escape it myself.

I know this works: `"abc".gsub("b") { |x| "\\\7" }` .. but being ruby such a beatifull language to learn up to now I belive there should be a simple alternative I'm overlooking in the docs.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're after (if it is, I can post this as answer): `s = 'abc'; s['b'] = '\7.0'; s`.

Comment: That will replace the first ocurrence, as with sub.. but I need gsub (replace all).

Answer (score 6):

<s>You can use</s> (**edit**: no you can't) `Regexp.escape` to escape user-provided strings:

```
user_input = '\7'
puts "abc".gsub("b", Regexp.escape(user_input))
a\7c
```

Otherwise escaping using single quotes instead of double:

```
puts "abc".gsub("b", '\\\7')
a\7c
```

...or with double quotes you just need more escaping:

```
puts "abc".gsub("b", "\\\\7")
a\7c
```

...or block notation, but you can skip the block-variable just fine:

```
puts "abc".gsub("b") { '\7' }
a\7c
```

Comment: this doesn't works:
puts "abc".gsub("b", Regexp.escape('\7.0')) >> a\7\.0c
there is another backslash added I don't know why..

Comment: @pragmatic_programmer - You are right. My bad. You can't use `Regexp.escape` in this instance. It won't work. So for your case it leaves only the last option (block notation), or qdiesel's answer.

Comment: @pragmatic_programmer - One more option is to escape the escapes with another gsub, but that starts to look pretty ugly. So you'd do: `gsub("b", user_input.gsub('\\', '\\\\\\'))`.

Comment: block notation definitely looks better than mine solution

Comment: three \ is error prone. If the following character is \ or `'`, you have to escape it again. Just use 4 \.

Comment: I've been bitten by `\'`. Option #4 is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ irb 
irb(main):001:0> replace='xxx\7.0\yyy'
=> "xxx\\7.0\\yyy"
irb(main):002:0> puts  "abc".gsub("b", replace.dump[1..-2])
axxx\7.0\yyyc
=> nil
```

Comment: It's works.. but the [1..-2] looks pretty cryptic.. the block notation it's more clear. This is the first time ruby surprises me!